# Matlab overcoming 'exceed matrix dimensions' without changing point of code

Tags: matlab

This matrix below is a 25x7 matrix. Basically what I'm doing is taking a start date and an end date, and adding 1 to the start date, and subtracting 1 from the end date. The problem is when I get to the last (25th) iteration, where my index exceeds the matrix dimensions. Here the start date is 20081210 and I need to get 20081211. How can I do so without changing the methodology of my code? Thank you.

```
 for i = 1:length(matrix)
      plus1=matrix(i+1,1);
      minus1=matrix(i,2)-1;
      [~,startIdx]=ismember(plus1,date); % index days in between entry date and exit date
      [~,cutoffIdx]=ismember(minus1,date); % index days in between entry date and exit date
      j=date(startIdx:cutoffIdx);
  end
```

Comment: I don't understand how your data is structured nor the point of your code. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with your desired output.

Comment: I don't understand what `matrix` and what `date` contain.

Comment: The first column of matrix is business dates. 20080825 to 20081210. The matrix contains the value of option spreads. I am trying to track the value on each successive day. I want the for loop to end at 20081211 but I can't do it without exceeding dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop will always exceed the length of `matrix` and therefore error out.

```
for i = 1:length(matrix)
    plus1 = matrix(i + 1, 1); % What happens when i == length(matrix)?
    % i + 1 = 26 which is greater than the rows in matrix
```

You need to change your loop limits to

```
for i = 1:length(matrix) - 1
    plus1 = matrix(i + 1, 1); % the max value of i + 1 will be the length of matrix
```

I have no idea if the rest is correct because you have not fully defined `matrix` nor `date`

Comment: I just suggested an edit. Didn't realize the loop. You wrote was abbreviated. Ignored if you like.